# Loading an external library such as Tabulator into Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

Is it possible to import an external library (in this case Tabulator) into GAS? I've tried using the eval() function and it simply says Syntax Error whenever I attempt to use it. Many thanks

Comment: Check what version of emcascript the library is compatible with. Odds are you need to transpile the library into an older version of JavaScript since Google Apps Script does not support many newer syntax structures.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out, since GAS only allows HTML and GS files in the project I had to reference and include the library from a server repository in the html file